How to implement Attach service that contain a 3rd-party library gor iOS
for now, Gluon-attach service for Push notification is using Firebase library for handling the push notification on Android, and this handling is done natively on iOS.
I want to add Firebase library for handling the notification in the iOS implementation too
I can not find any help about how to do that, and I did not find any example about **how to add and use a library for iOS attch-service! **
Can you help !!
